# Eclipse: The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches

Tags: eclipse

So, I know that there are many people with this problem and many questions about it, but I just couldn't fin a solution for this, every other thing I try to execute works, but this doesn't and I can't figure out why...

```
package prob3;
```

public class LargestPrimeFactor {

```
double num = 600851475143D;
double LargestPrimeFactor;

public void getLargestPrimeFactor(String [] args){

    double prevPrimeFactor = 0;

    do {

        for(double i = 0; i < num/2; i++){

            if((num % i == 0) && (num / i != 1)){

                prevPrimeFactor = num;
                LargestPrimeFactor = num / i;

            } else {

                continue;

            }

        }

    } while(prevPrimeFactor != LargestPrimeFactor);

    System.out.println("The biggest prime factor of " + num + " is " + LargestPrimeFactor);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you should define a main function to run your program. Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getLargestPrimeFactor(args);
}
```